# Why is the partial derivative continuous but not differentiable at this point

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, binary

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
    0  & \quad x>1,y>1\\
    \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}  & \quad \text{else}
  \end{cases}$$
There is a point B$(1,1)$ ,and the partial derivatives are continuous at this point 
[image]
However,$f(x,y)$ is not continuous and not differentiable at this point 
If the partial derivative is continuous, function must be differentiable at some point
why is it wrong?Did I get my understanding wrong?

Comment: The partial derivatives exist but are not continuous.

Comment: when $x=1,f_{y}=\displaystyle\frac{-y}{\sqrt{8-y^2}}$ ?

Comment: What about when $x \ne 1$? We need $f_y(x,y)$ to be continuous in both variables.

Comment: @ColeG97 when we calaulate $f_{y}(x,y)$ at some point, shouldn't the "$x$"  be considered as a constant?
+ You mean to say that I want to analyze the continuity of partial derivatives at this point, should I take into account the partial derivatives of all points in its neighborhood?
+ If we take into account the exist ,should we just need to calculate the partial derivative of this point?

Comment: I need to get some sleep first, please forgive me if there is no immediate response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to your comment above in the form of an answer...

The partial derivatives do indeed exist at $(1,1)$, but they are not continuous there. Let's take a look at $f_y$. For $x\le1,y\le1$ we have
$$f_y(x,y) = -\frac{y}{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}$$
as you computed above. For $x > 1, y>1$ $f_y(x,y) = 0$. We will now show $f_y$ is discontinous at $(1,1)$. Let $h > 0$, we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}|f_y(1+h,1+h) - f(1,1)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}$$
Thus, $f_y$ is not continous at $(1,1)$. A similar argument shows that $f_x$ is also discontinuous at $(1,1)$. Remember the definition of continuity for multivariable functions – it goes:

$g(x,y)$ is continous at $(x_0,y_0)$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that **for all** $(x,y)\neq (x_0,y_0)$ in the open disk centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ of radius $\delta$, we have
$$|g(x,y) - g(x_0,y_0)| < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: I have understood that Although the definition of a partial derivative at a point is to find the limit of a univariate function(the other variable is considered as a constant), **the partial derivative is actually a binary function**

Thankyou for your great answer:)